# How to get current-menu-item title as variable?

Tags: menus, title

Is possible to get current-menu-item as a php variable?

I'm listing the category museums via the menu item 'museums we support' so i'd like the get 'museums we support' bit and display it somewhere?

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is possible by filtering `wp_nav_menu_objects`, which is the easiest place to check which item is the current menu item, because [WordPress already added the classes for you](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1.2/wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php#L192).

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_objects', 'wpse16243_wp_nav_menu_objects' );
function wpse16243_wp_nav_menu_objects( $sorted_menu_items )
{
    foreach ( $sorted_menu_items as $menu_item ) {
        if ( $menu_item->current ) {
            $GLOBALS['wpse16243_title'] = $menu_item->title;
            break;
        }
    }
    return $sorted_menu_items;
}
```

You can now use this new global variable instead of the normal title. Simple example:

```
add_filter( 'single_cat_title', 'wpse16243_single_cat_title' );
function wpse16243_single_cat_title( $cat_title )
{
    if ( isset( $GLOBALS['wpse16243_title'] ) ) {
        return $GLOBALS['wpse16243_title'];
    }
    return $cat_title;
}
```

Of course, this only works if you display the menu before you display the title. If you need it earlier (maybe in the `<title>` element?), you should [first render the menu and then display it later](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14430/minor-css-change-based-on-topmenu-how/14466#14466).

Comment: hello Jan - just wondering if there's a way to create an array of the $menu_item->current items' children? Tried several things but not getting very far..!

Comment: managed this with the help of your filter - answer below. Cheers!

Comment: Jan Fabry / I tried using `wpse16243_wp_nav_menu_objects` to retrieve current menu ID. But it's not consistant. Switching between home page and a menu item does nto always give me correct menu item  - it kind of "lags". Any suggestion on how I can retrieve current menu ID?

Comment: Is there a reason why you preface the function name with `wpse16243`? I see this strange type of name fairly common and wondering what it's all about. *Disclaimer: Wordpress noob.*

Comment: @Steve: Just a unique prefix: `WordPress Stack Exchange question number 16243`. If people directly copy this code, it won't conflict with other plugins that might share the same function names.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`wp_get_nav_menu_items()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_nav_menu_items). Here's a sample `function`:

```
<?php
function my_get_menu_item_name( $loc ) {
    global $post;

    $locs = get_nav_menu_locations();

    $menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object( $locs[$loc] );

    if($menu) {

        $items = wp_get_nav_menu_items($menu->term_id);

        foreach ($items as $k => $v) {
            // Check if this menu item links to the current page
            if ($items[$k]->object_id == $post->ID) {
                $name = $items[$k]->title;
                break;
            }
        }

    }
    return $name;
}
```

Then call the `function` with the **location name** of the **nav menu** you wish to use:

```
<?php
$menu_name = my_get_menu_item_name( 'NAV_MENU_LOCATION_NAME' ); // eg. 'primary'

echo $menu_name;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_objects', 'wpse16243_wp_nav_menu_objects' );
function wpse16243_wp_nav_menu_objects( $sorted_menu_items )
{
    foreach ( $sorted_menu_items as $menu_item ) {

        if ($menu_item->current ) {
            $GLOBALS['currentMenuTitle'] = $menu_item->title;
            $GLOBALS['currentMenuID'] = $menu_item->ID;



            break;
        }
    }


    return $sorted_menu_items;
}


function get_menu_items_children( $menu_item_id='' )
{   
    global $wpdb;

      //     AND meta_key='_menu_item_menu_item_parent'

    $myrows = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->postmeta JOIN $wpdb->posts ON $wpdb->postmeta.post_id=$wpdb->posts.id WHERE meta_value = '".$menu_item_id."' AND meta_key='_menu_item_menu_item_parent' ORDER BY $wpdb->posts.menu_order ASC" );


    foreach ( $myrows as $menu_item ) {

        $sc = get_object_vars($menu_item);  

        $myrowsb = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE post_id = '".$sc['post_id']."' AND meta_key='_menu_item_object_id' " );

        foreach ( $myrowsb as $menu_itemb ) {

            $scb = get_object_vars($menu_itemb);    
            $pmIDs[] = $scb['meta_value'];

        }

    }


    return $pmIDs;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I exactly follow.

The "Museums We Support" is generated by a Post Title, Page Title, Category Title, etc. (or, if you're using a Custom Navigation Menu, it could be a custom Title).

What are you trying to do with this text? Where are you trying to display it? I assume you're trying to display it on the Category Index Page (since you indicate it is `current-menu-item`)? If so, simply call `<?php single_cat_title(); ?>` to output the Category Title.

If you need additional category information, you can use something like:

```
$cat = get_the_category();
$currentcat = $cat[0];
```

Which makes available the following variables:

```
$currentcat=>cat_ID // Category ID
$currentcat=>cat_name // Category Name (Same as Title)
$currentcat=>category_nicename // Category Slug
$currentcat=>category_description // Category Description
$currentcat=>category_count // Category Count (# of Posts w/ this Category)
```

If you're somewhere *other* than the Category Index Page, you'll need to pass the $catid to these functions.

EDIT:

Since you indicated that "Museums We Support" is a custom Menu Title, the *easiest* approach would be to *rename the Category* from "Museums" to "Museums We Support" (note: you can leave the slug, `museums`, unchanged). However, doing so would mean that "Museums We Support" would be displayed as the Category Title wherever else it might be output in your template. If that is acceptable, then no worries.

Otherwise, you will have to use something like `wp_get_nav_menu_items()` ([Codex ref](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_nav_menu_items)) in order to grab the Title for the specific menu item.

Comment: hey chip - its this page ; http://bfami.modernactivity.co.uk/category/museum/ so basically the cat is 'museum' but i want to show the 'MUSEUMS WE SUPPORT' which is the navigation label (custom title) set in the menus page. Think its possible to grab that somehow?

Comment: That helps. See my answer edit. You have a couple options: rename the Category, or use `wp_get_nav_menu_items()`.

Comment: cheers chip - just changed the category title in the end! Just thought there would be an easy way to grab the menu label...