# How do you get the current-menu-item ID?

Tags: menus

Im trying to get the id of the menu item that has be class called "current-menu-item". Not the current page id, but the nav item id.

Please help

Comment: I once figured out [how to get the current menu item title](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16243/how-to-get-current-menu-item-title-as-variable/16337#16337), you should be able to adapt it to return the ID instead.

Answer (score 4):

A little late perhaps, but there is one more way of doing it:

```
$menu = wp_get_nav_menu_items($menu_id,array(
   'posts_per_page' => -1,
   'meta_key' => '_menu_item_object_id',
   'meta_value' => $post->ID // the currently displayed post
));

var_dump($menu[0]->ID);
```

Since menu items are post-types you are able to use all the WP-Query params, even a meta query. The code above selects all menu_items which are connected to the current post, from the menu you specify via `$menu_id`.

Answer (score 3):

This should solve it [How to get current-menu-item title as variable?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16243/how-to-get-current-menu-item-title-as-variable/16337#16337)

but change

```
$GLOBALS['wpse16243_title'] = $menu_item->title;
```

to

```
$GLOBALS['wpse16243_title'] = $menu_item->ID;
```

and now you can use the global variable `$wpse16243_title` to get the ID

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be to use the `nav_menu_css_class` filter. Something like this would work:

```
function wpse19375_nav_class( $classes, $item ){
  if( !in_array( 'current-menu-item', $classes ) )
    return $classes;
  // $item is a 'current-menu-item' object.
  return $classes;
}

add_filter( 'nav_menu_css_class', 'wpse19375_nav_class', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: thanks mate, but i don't understand how this will bring the id

Comment: The `$item` variable is the menu object. It has all the information you could want, including the ID.

Comment: @John P Bloch, But what are you returning `$classes` to?